# Why does my list reduction over gamepad timestamps result in NaN?

Tags: javascript, gamepad

I have a simple reduction in JavaScript:

```
navigator.getGamepads().reduce((i, j) => i.timestamp * j.timestamp, 1)
```

When there are no gamepads, the result is `1`.

When there is one gamepad, the result is `NaN`.

However, the list is of `number` values:

```
navigator.getGamepads().map(x => x.timestamp)
Array [ 280868.92 ]

navigator.getGamepads().map(x => typeof x.timestamp)
Array [ "number" ]
```

Why is this?

---

I am using Firefox 54.0 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce function in `navigator.getGamepads().reduce((i, j) => i.timestamp * j.timestamp, 1)` gets 1 as the first argument for the first iteration. `timestamp` property of 1 is `undefined`, this is why you get NaN.

You may try something like this:

`navigator.getGamepads().reduce((i, j) => i.timestamp * j.timestamp, {timestamp: 1})`

Answer (score 1):

When there are no gamepads, the result is 1. Because your initial value is 1. This is the second argument of your reduce function :

```
navigator.getGamepads().reduce((i, j) => i.timestamp * j.timestamp, 1)
```

- first argument  : `(i, j) => i.timestamp * j.timestamp`
- second argument : 1

When there is one gamepad, you apply your function to myGamepad, and 1

```
(1, myGamepad) => 1.timestamp * myGamepad.timestamp
```

myGamepad has a timestamp, but your initial value has none, so it returns a NaN

Maybe you could create an initial value like this

```
let initValue = {timestamp: 1}
navigator.getGamepads().reduce((i, j) => i.timestamp * j.timestamp, initValue )
```